# Spring Data - JPA Repository - Too many parameters in a Query

Tags: postgresql, spring-data

I'm working with Spring Data Repositories manipulating data from a PostreSQL database.

In one of my repositories, I have a very simple query:

```
@Query(value = "FROM MyEntity entity WHERE entity.entityId IN (:entityIds)")
Collection<MyEntity> getEntitiesByIds(@Param("entityIds") Collection<Long> entityIds);
```

The problem is, when I pass in a collection that has more than 32k~ ids this query throws the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value: 70324
```

I did some research and  found out that this error happens because postgresql jdbc driver has a limit of 32k~ parameters you can pass in to a query. So I have two options here:

1. Do the query in batches. At this point I think this is my best shot but I was hoping to find a solution so I can pull my rows in one database call.
2. Build a temporary table with the ids, then join it against MyEntity table, but I'm running again into the same original problem. For this approach I was thinking to pass a String with all the concatenated ids and then use a native query to pull the information but it its not working as I expected:

   ```
   @Query(value = ";WITH cteAllEntityIds(entity_id) AS( " +
               "VALUES (?1)) " +
               "SELECT p.* FROM my_entity e " +
               "JOIN cteAllEntityIds cte ON e.entity_id = cte.entity_id", nativeQuery = true)
   ```

   `Collection<ProfileViewEntity> getProfilesByIds(String profileIds);`

Of course, the parameter I'm passing in is a String whereas the entity_id is a number in the data base.

Do you know a way to accomplish approach #2? How to build queries dynamically and make jpa to interpret it that way?

Do you know a better solution to this problem?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.